# Hibernate app as WebJob in Azure "Could not open connection" exception

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, azure

I created a `WebJob` in Azure using a jar file with a `Hibernate` `Java` application. The app is running with no issues on my local machine, while connecting to a `MySql` database on the Azure platform.

But when I run it as a WebJob I get this exception:

```
ERROR: Communications link failure
[02/22/2016 15:04:27 > 78b5cd: ERR ] 
[02/22/2016 15:04:27 > 78b5cd: ERR ] The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
[02/22/2016 15:04:27 > 78b5cd: ERR ] org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
[02/22/2016 15:04:27 > 78b5cd: ERR ]    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131)
[02/22/2016 15:04:27 > 78b5cd: ERR ]    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
[02/22/2016 15:04:27 > 78b5cd: ERR ]    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
[02/22/2016 15:04:27 > 78b5cd: ERR ]    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
[02/22/2016 15:04:27 > 78b5cd: ERR ]    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
[02/22/2016 15:04:27 > 78b5cd: ERR ]    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
[02/22/2016 15:04:27 > 78b5cd: ERR ]    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
[02/22/2016 15:04:27 > 78b5cd: ERR ]    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
[02/22/2016 15:04:27 > 78b5cd: ERR ]    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1309)
[02/22/2016 15:04:27 > 78b5cd: ERR ]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[02/22/2016 15:04:27 > 78b5cd: ERR ]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[02/22/2016 15:04:27 > 78b5cd: ERR ]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[02/22/2016 15:04:27 > 78b5cd: ERR ]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[02/22/2016 15:04:27 > 78b5cd: ERR ]    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
[02/22/2016 15:04:27 > 78b5cd: ERR ]    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)
[02/22/2016 15:04:27 > 78b5cd: ERR ]    at com.antiquemails.manager.DatabaseManager.findSearchesToEmail(DatabaseManager.java:25)
[02/22/2016 15:04:27 > 78b5cd: ERR ]    at com.antiquemails.mailsearches.MyMailManager.main(MyMailManager.java:73)
[02/22/2016 15:04:27 > 78b5cd: ERR ] Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Just so there's no confusion as to the nature of the problem: the app is running on my local machine while hitting the database on `Azure`. The `WebJob` is starting, and finishing with a `Success` message. But when trying to connect to the database it dies with the exception above.

What am I missing here? How do I deploy the app as a WebJob?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I think there are two scenarios below corresponded with your issue.

1. Your WebApp was missing MySQL/ClearDB as the linked resource that you can set up on the tab `LINKED RESOURCES` of Azure old portal or on the `All Settings -> General -> Application Settings` of Azure new portal.
2. According to [the section `Outbound Network Addresses` of the doc `Network Architecture Overview of App Service Environments`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-app-service-environment-network-architecture-overview/#outbound-network-addresses), the jdbc driver connect to MySQL via the outbound traffic of Azure App Service Environment. So you can try to refer to the doc https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-app-service-environment-network-configuration-expressroute/#enabling-outbound-network-connectivity-for-an-app-service-environment to enable the outbound network connectivity.

For being sure the MySQL connection can be connected, you can follow the last section `How do I connect to my MySQL Database on ClearDB?` of the doc https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/05/07/troubleshooting-mysql-database-on-cleardb/ to do it.

---

**Update** Pic: The place to adding linked resource on Azure new portal
[image]

Comment: I'm looking at (1) first. But I can't find a place to add a linked resource at All Settings -> General -> Application. I'm pretty sure this is the new portal, at https://portal.azure.com

Comment: I added the hibernate.connection.url but that didn't help. Just to make sure I'm getting my point across, the app itself is already connecting to the MySql db with no issues at all. The only thing that is not currently connecting is the WebJob.